# How to START a program with a space in the relative path?

Tags: batch-file, relative-path, subdirectory

I am trying to use the relative path to call a VBS file.
We'll call the file Something.vbs for example.
The file is located in a folder with a space so D:\folder\Folder with a space\ for example.
I use the following code

```
start %~dp0Something.VBS
```

Bu I get an error stating that the folder D:\folder\Folder does not exist.

I have tried playing with the relative path operator with this

```
start "%~dp0"Something.VBS
```

and

```
start "%~dp0Something.VBS"
```

But just end up getting a prompt for the reset of the file path.

Any help or idias would be greate, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
start "This is the window title" "%~dp0Something.VBS"
```

There's a quirk with `start` - the quoted name is assumed to be the window title.

Comment: To be precise: the first quoted string in the command line after `start` is assumed to be a window title. Just passing `""` suffices as well.